# How to show images in lightbox onclick of menuitem?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, lightbox, menuitem

I need your help in displaying two images in a lightbox on click of a menuitem. I used the below code:

```
<p:menubar id="mymenu" autoDisplay="true">
    <p:lightBox styleClass="imagebox" id="lighbox1">
        <h:outputLink id="a" value="/resources/images/t1.png" title="Request1">
            <p:menuitem value="Help" style="height:16px;width:120px" icon="ui-icon-notice"/>
        </h:outputLink>

        <h:outputLink id="b" value="/resources/images/t2.jpg" title="Request2"/>
    </p:lightBox>
</p:menubar>
```

I tried the above code and it generated an error that lightbox can not be vast to menuitem, so is there any workaround to do this?

Comment: If it was every going to work, shouldn't the `lightBox` go inside a `menuitem`? You've nested things the exact opposite way of what you've described your intention to be. I'm not saying it's going to work, but as a first attempt, I'd at least fix that. Regardless, the PrimeFaces documentation says the root of `menubar` must be `submenu` or `menuitem`.

Comment: Correct the menu order first. So do you have two menu items or one?

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary I want to have a menuitem which is called "Help" and when I click on it, I want to view the two images. So how can I do this?

Comment: @DavidS I have followed the documentation and this didn't work properly

Comment: You're already _not_ following the documentation: the documentation says that `p:lightBox` cannot be a child of `p:menuBar`.

Comment: Hey I'm facing the same problem. Did you find out the solution? If yes then please answer it here.

Comment: @HARSHITASETHI This can not be done and replace it with other components